# Returning text to a button from a database C# DataColumnCollection

Tags: c#, ms-access-2013

I'm attempting to build a POS system, I currently have an access database that stores all my menu `items` as strings.
I wish for the buttons (stored within an array) to display this text.

Currently my algorithm works for a single item in the database without an issue, however when I increase the amount of entries I get this error:
[image: 2 Entries]

The weird thing is, is that `dr[count].ToString();` returns the correct data as far as I can tell.
[image: Returned Data]

This is my code:

```
    private void main_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Database db = new Database();
        DataRowCollection dra = db.ReturnDataRowCollection("SELECT itemname FROM menuitems WHERE Category = 'main'");
        int count = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dra)
        {
            btns[count].Text = dr[count].ToString();
            btns[count].Visible = true;
            count++;
        }
    }
```

It is exactly the same code for both starter and main.

For reference this is a screenshot of my Access Database:
[image: Access DB]

Comment: it seems u r using wrong value from datarow. use dr[0].ToString(). Becuase you are looping for each datarow & having only one column in the datarow..

Comment: @anupam-sharma I have multiple columns, so what changes would I need to make?

Comment: You can put the column name like dr["itemname"].ToString(). incase you are reading this column value.

Comment: @anupam-sharma How would that work? Could you please attempt to write an example algorithm please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
private void main_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Database db = new Database();
        DataRowCollection dra = db.ReturnDataRowCollection("SELECT itemname FROM menuitems WHERE Category = 'main'");
        int count = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dra)
        {
            btns[count].Text = dr["itemname"].ToString();
            btns[count].Visible = true;
            count++;
        }
    }
```

What I have understand is your all buttons text are stored in the same column. Only the rows are different. So this code should work. Please try this and let me know if it works or not......

Comment: ah, thank you very much. I didn't quite understand what that value was for.

Answer (score 0):

`IndexOutOfRangeException` is thrown when you try to use an element located at an index which is outside the range. You need to make sure that both `btns[count]` and `dr[count]` are defined. I believe your problem is with `dr[count]`, because you try to locate the element in each row located at `count` index. Unless your button in each row is located at the column having the index of the row, this is where you have the problem. I believe all your buttons are located in the same columns.